# Oracle dB automatically retrieve new records

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, oracle11g

What is the best way for a c# application to automatically execute a sql statement or stored procedure to automatically get newest records from an oracle database?

I was searching the web but could not find an answer for this.

Should I create a timer and let the app constantly run a select query every minute? I guess this will have an impact on performance if there are multiple clients executing that query.

As always, your answers will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the reasoning for keeping a full list up to date at all times on all clients? I only ask as it may help inform an answer better.

Comment: Let's say I would like to create a help desk app, when a new request is being added by a customer all instances of that app should automatically receive it from the dB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in this topic you can use [Continuous Query Notification](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/dotnet/changenotification/index.html)